# Use PHP code in Menu Admin Section

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, twitter-bootstrap

**wp_nav_menu()**

```
 <!-- Cart Menu -->
            <?php 
              wp_nav_menu([
               'menu'            => 'Cart',
               'theme_location'  => 'Cart',
               'container'       => false,
               //'container_id'    => 'bs4navbar',
               //'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
               'menu_id'         => false,
               'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
               'depth'           => 2,
               'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
               'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
             ]);
            ?>
                    <!-- code for the badge START-->
            <?php $args = array(
              'menu' => 'Cart',
              'container' => '',
              'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
            ); ?>
            <ul class="badge">
            <?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
            <li>

              <?php
            if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() !== 0 ) {
            // Do something fun
              ?>  
              <span class="badge-pill badge-warning no-md-view">
                <a class="cart-customlocation" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf ( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ); ?></a>
              <?php 
            }
            ?>

            </span>

            </li>
            </ul>
```

**Result**

[image]

---

I want to add my PHP code to add a Bagde in my link using the wodpress menu admin.

I already add the code to the header (navbar), but I'd like to add it like a Badge in my cart icon.

[image]

Is anybody knows what happens?

Comment: You haven't closed the span tag and typically it's not a wise idea to float spans. Try floating the `<a>` tag instead and place the span inside it.

Comment: @WebElaine I closed the <span> and the result was the same. I did all these tests and if I use just the PHP code, the browser (or wordpress) renders it as a comment <!-- -->. Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: Try taking out the comment above your code `<!-- code for the badge START-->`. Other than that we probably would need to see more of your code to help. As @Jeff Mattson mentioned this may be the wrong code block you are working on. See if it is anywhere else in your theme or plugins.

Comment: @WebElaine please, see edit. I put my full code there, Badge is ok there, the problem is when I use the PHP code inside de admin menu section. tks!

Comment: I think a little may be getting lost in translation. front-page.php is not an admin page. It's a front end visitor facing page. I personally find it best to simplify: instead of using your full code, try just outputting something simple. So inside your if statement, just put `<a href="foo">I am working</a>` and see if that works. If not, it has nothing to do with your badge code, it's something outside/before it that's causing it to appear as a comment.

Comment: I think I'm not clear. Let's try again. When I meant "admin page", It means the wordpress admin area, where we post content, add plugins, widgets and set-up the menu área. The badge code is working. I'm using this code  in my navbar, cart page etc. But I'm looking for a way to use it with my cart icon, like a notification badge to show the costumer that we have one or more itens inside the cart. I hope you can understand better now.

Answer (score 0):

Allan, thanks for clarifying the question. You can't add PHP in the wp-admin menu manager. Instead, here is a way to keep the menu dynamic and managed in wp-admin, while still allowing you to add your PHP at the end:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'menu' => 'your-menu-name',
    'container' => '',
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
); ?>
<ul class="my-custom-menu">
<?php wp_nav_menu($args); ?>
<li><?php // add your badge code here ?></li>
</ul>
```

What this does: outputs a menu named `your-menu-name` (replace this with whatever you're calling the menu, looks like it may be `cart`). Leaving `container` empty means it removes the `<div>` that normally wraps around the menu. You want to remove that because if you don't, you'll have a `<div>` around the menu but not your badge. Setting `items_wrap` to just `%3$s` strips off the `<ul>` that normally wraps around the menu - you're removing it for the same reason you're removing the `<div>`. Finally, you wrap both the menu and your custom code within your own `<ul>` - you can change `my-custom-menu` to whatever CSS class you like, add an ID, etc. - and by putting your badge code inside an `<li>` it will then get the same CSS styles such as float that your other menu items are getting.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I have a little problem :).I already have a custom args to my wp_nav_menu(). I'll add another comment to explain better. Is is full. 
<?php
   wp_nav_menu([
   'menu'            => 'top',
   'theme_location'  => 'top',
   'container'       => 'div',
   'container_id'    => 'bs4navbar',
   'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
   'menu_id'         => false,
   'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
   'depth'           => 2,
   'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
   'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
 ]);
 ?>

Comment: First step: I used the code as you wrote, it create an bagde with all itens of my original menu.
Second step: I mixed your code with mine. If I remove 'div' and '<li>' or keep both my code broke (no CSS). It worked, but the 'style' and 'js' didn't.

Comment: Right, this will change the HTML elements, so you can either go back and edit your CSS, or, you can hard-code the outer `<div>` with the same class it had before and set the `<ul>` class to whatever it was before.

Comment: I did what I told me, but I don't know if I undertand eveything. I edit one more time my question to show you the result. You can see more of my code (and evolution stage) here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267827/add-dropdown-menu-using-add-filter-wp-nav-menu-items